# Why there is access to package-private methods from different package if I evaluate expression during debug using IDE?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

For example if I have class A:

```
class A {
   void xxx() {};
}
```

and class B in different package:

```
class B {
   public void yyy() {
      new A().xxx()  // Wont compile, but can evaluate this expression during debug if put here breakpoint
   }
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't compile, your IDE is probably using a previously compiled version in which your code was valid

Comment: Exactly as @CocoNess noted you might have a version that compiled without the current package-private access. It just inconceivable that you'll even be able to debug a program with compiled errors.

Comment: No compile > no run > no debug > no evaluation! Please clean your project from previously compiled versions of your classes.